# Perl Can't load XS.xs.dll and perl528.dll is missing

Tags: perl, dll

When I run the following command

```
D:\05_project>perl xml_export.pl  xml_20190626.xml
```

it produces xml-files from a MariaDB. It works very well the last 6 month. I used Perl version **5.28** on Windows 7/64bit.

Last week I removed Perl 5.28 and installed Perl **5.30**. Many Perl-scripts works without causing problems but the `xml_export.pl` breaks after starting. The first what happenend is to give a system error:

[image]

Then the following message was put on the terminal:

```
Can't load 'C:\PerlLib\lib\perl5/MSWin32-x64-multi-thread/auto/Date/Calc/XS/XS.xs.dll' 
for module Date::Calc::XS: load_file:
The specified module could not befound at 
C:/Program2/Strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
       at C:\PerlLib\lib\perl5/Date/Calc.pm line 26.

Compilation failed in require at C:\PerlLib\lib\perl5/Date/Calc.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\PerlLib\lib\perl5/Date/Calc.pm line 43.
Compilation failed in require at xml_export.pl line 67.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at xml_export.pl line 67.
```

I'm wondering what happened and how can I solve this problem. The package Date::Calc is installed. Perl is installed in drive C and I run perl scripts from drive c and d. As mentioned, I had no problem until I installed the new version of Perl. I reinstalled Perl 5.30 but the problem persists. Any idea?

**Update 1:**

If I comment out the package `Date::Calc` in `xml_export.pl`

```
# -- date computations                   # line 66 
# use Date::Calc qw(:all);               # line 67
```

The script works now. So, the question remains why it does not work when adding this package and why this strange system error (missing perl528.dll) is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Date::Calc](http://p3rl.org/Date::Calc) has an XS component [Date::Calc::XS](http://p3rl.org/Date::Calc::XS), i.e. it needs to compile some C code. When you upgrade Perl, you need to recompile all the XS modules so they work with the new Perl version. The installed package is linked against a library that doesn't exist anymore (which is what the System Error window tells you).

Reinstalling Date::Calc should fix the issue, but make sure all other XS modules are updated, too.

Comment: It would probably be best to delete/move the whole `C:\PerlLib\` and reinstall everything that was there.

Comment: @choroba I'm very happy to know where the problem is located. I reinstalled first Date::Calc but still it did not work. Also I tried to install Date::Calc::XS (Using `perl -MCPAN -e shell`). It still gives the same errors. Which other package could be involved? @Grinnz: I'm not so confident in Perl to remove the whole library. One question: Can I just install the packages or should I remove first the old packages?

Comment: Just rename it to PerlLib.backup, install the modules, run the tests. You can always rename it back to return to the (non working) old version.

Comment: @choroba Thanks, good idea and it works. The only thing is that it is not so clear what was the package name. In R, for example, package name is the name as the folder, in Perl it is not so clear.

Comment: In Perl, `package Foo::Bar;` loads `Foo/Bar.pm`. The directories in which Perl looks are given by `perl -le'print for @INC;'`